# What is the Banach-Mazur distance between $\ell_\infty$ and $L_\infty$?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Given Banach spaces $X$ and $Y$, the Banach-Mazur distance between $X$ and $Y$ is defined as
$$ d(X,Y) = \inf\{ \|\varphi\|\|\varphi^{-1}\| : \varphi\colon X\to Y \text{ isomorphism} \}.
$$
We consider the Banach spaces $\ell_\infty=\ell_\infty(\mathbb{N})$ and $L_\infty=L_\infty([0,1],\lambda)$, where $\lambda$ is the Lebesgue measure on $[0,1]$.

> What is $d(\ell_\infty,L_\infty)$?

Comment: Is there any reason to think that it is finite ?

Comment: @DenisSerre: $l^\infty$ and $L^\infty$ are isomorphic as Banach spaces. I think this is due to Pelczynski.

Comment: Yes, it is well known that they are isomorphic. This follows from the injectivity of these spaces and Pelczynski decomposition method. The details can be found, for instance, in Albiac-Kalton. I am not sure if the answer to the question is known though.

Comment: Yes, they are isomorphic and therefore the distance is finite.

Comment: Banach spaces $l^\infty$ and $L^\infty$ are isomorphic, but isomorphisms are not constructive.  Something like the Hahn-Banach theorem is required to prove the existence of an isomorphism.

Comment: See [this discussion](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/110438/is-there-an-explicit-isomorphism-between-l-infty0-1-and-ell-infty)  of that non-constructivity (in particular t.b.'s answer which shows that in $ZF + DC + PM_\omega$ they are not isomorphic).

Comment: If this is relevant, I am interested in the situation assuming ZFC.

Comment: Reading the "construction" given by Theo Buehler (see @RobertIsrael's comment) my guess would be that one can get a BM-distance of $\leq 4$ by careful book-keeping of the isomorphisms, since both $Y=\ell_\infty$ and $X=L_\infty$ are $1$-injective, and since $X\cong_1 X\oplus_\infty X$ and $Y\cong_1 Y\oplus_\infty Y$

Comment: I was not aware of the Amir-Cambern theorem, which gives a nice lower bound $d(\ell_\infty,L_\infty)\geq 2$. I looked a little bit at this topic now, and found the paper "A second-dual method for C(X) isomorphisms" by Cohen, J. Funct. Anal. 23 (1976). It contains results about C(K) spaces with BM-distance $<3$. Does anybody see if this can be used to show $d(\ell_\infty,L_\infty)\geq 3$ ?

Comment: @YemonChoi Following the construction from the post of Theo Buehler, I understand that $d(X,X\oplus_\infty Y)\leq 4$, and similarly $d(X\oplus_\infty Y,Y)\leq 4$, for $X=L_\infty$ and $Y=\ell_\infty$. But this only gives $d(X,Y)\leq 16$, Do you think that $d(X,X\oplus_\infty Y)\leq 2$? Since $X$ and $X\oplus_\infty Y$ are not isometrically isomorphic, we have $d(X,X\oplus_\infty Y)\geq 2$. With an upper bound of $2$, we would thus get $d(X,X\oplus_\infty Y)=2$.

Comment: @HannesThiel I admit I did not think this through very carefully. My idea (which may have a silly mistake) was to get a positive norm-1 projection $P$ from $L_\infty$ onto $\ell_\infty$, in which case $I-P$ should also be a positive norm-1 projection (I think?) onto the complementary subspace.

Comment: @YemonChoi That is a nice idea. Certainly $X=L_\infty$ and $Y=\ell_\infty$ are injective Banach lattices. It looks like the embedding $\ell_\infty \to L_\infty$ (from the post of Theo Buehler) does identify $\ell_\infty$ with a sublattice of $L_\infty$. Thus, one would get a positive projection from $X$ onto $Y$. For the embedding $L_\infty \to \ell_\infty$ this is not clear to me. Maybe it is not possible to embed $L_\infty$ as a closed sublattice of $\ell_\infty$. There are structure results for lattice homomorphism $C(K_1)\to C(K_2)$, see e.g. 3.2.10 in "Banach Lattices" by Meyer-Nieberg.

Comment: Does the proof provide an upper bound?

Comment: Is there an argument that ZFC actually uniquely specifies the value of $d(\ell_\infty,L_\infty)$?

Comment: @JamesHanson I'm not sure I follow (since I am a caveman when it comes to set theory). Is your question whether additional axioms might allow one to "construct" isomorphisms $\ell_\infty \leftrightarrow L_\infty$ that have smaller norm than ones constructed with "bare" ZFC?

Comment: @YemonChoi That is basically what I am wondering, although I wouldn't necessarily phrase it in terms of axioms. I would phrase it like this: Is there a rational number $r$ such that $d(\ell_\infty,L_\infty) < r$ and $d(\ell_\infty,L_\infty) > r$ are both consistent with ZFC?

Answer (score 10):

Not a complete answer, feel free to edit. (Likely, the answer is not known anyway.) The distance is at least 2. Look at both spaces as $C(K)$ spaces. Corresponding $K$'s are not homeomorphic, see the discussion here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/207435/isometry-between-l-infty-and-ell-infty

So by Amir-Cambern theorem (near isometry property of $C(K)$ spaces) the distance is at least 2. The theorem says if there is an isomorphism between $C(K_1)$ and $C(K_2)$ with distortion strictly less than 2, then $K_1$ and $K_2$ are homeomorphic.

Comment: I don't think it is right that the unit ball of $L_\infty$ has more extreme points than the unit ball of $\ell_\infty$. Here's the argument in the real case. A point in the unit ball of $L_\infty$ is $2\mathbf 1_B-1$, where $B$ is a measurable set. Two such functions agree if the $B$'s differ by a set of measure 0. Any Lebesgue measurable $B$ agrees with a Borel $B$ up to a set of measure 0. The cardinality of the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $[0,1]$ is $\aleph_1$, the same as the cardinality of the collection of $\pm 1$ sequences.

Comment: Thanks for this. I will edit it once someone points out a correct argument for the non-isometry of these spaces.

Comment: Choose an extreme point of the unit ball, and call it $e$.  We can define a partial ordering on our space by $x \ge 0$ if $\|\|x\| e - x \| \le \|x\|$.  This makes $L_\infty$ or $\ell_\infty$ into a Banach lattice (equivalent by an isometry to the usual lattice structure).   Now $\ell^\infty$ has the property that it has minimal nonnegative elements of norm $1$, i.e. $x$ such that the only element $0 \le y \le x$ with $\|y\| = 1$ is $x$.  But $L_\infty$ does not have such elements.  So $\ell_\infty$ and $L_\infty$ are not isometric.

Comment: Doesn't this prove just that there's no lattice-preserving isometry from $\ell_\infty$ to $L_\infty$?

Comment: @AnthonyQuas this lattice is defined using norm and linear structures only, thus Robert's argument looks fine.

Comment: By the way, how to prove (if it is true in general, not only for $C(K)$ spaces) that whenever two spaces are not isometric, BM distance is strictly greater than 1?

Comment: It is not true, Fedor.  Take a sequence $p_n$ that strictly decreases to $1$ and consider $X= (\sum_{n=1}^\infty \ell_{p_n}^2)_2$. Then the BM distance of $X$ to $X\oplus_2 \ell_1^2$ is one but the spaces are not isometrically isomorphic because the latter one is not strictly convex.

Comment: Another way to express Robert Israel's comment is to say that the Stone space of $\ell_\infty$ has isolated points while the Stone space of $L_\infty$ does not.

Comment: @BillJohnson If $C(K_1)\cong C(K_2)$, how big can the BM-distance between them be? That is, do we have examples to show that the BM-distance can be arbitrarily big?

Comment: @YemonChoi Arbitrarily big, e.g., the distance between $C(\omega)$ and $C(\omega^n)$ tends to infinity as $n$ does.

Answer (score 2):

The distance is strictly greater than $2$ --- as is true for any compact, nonhomeomorphic $K_1$ and $K_2$ when $K_1$ is totally disconnected (Cohen-Chu, Stud. Math. 1995, p.6).  The question of an upper bound is more puzzling.  @HannesThiel comment 6/13/2016 suggests distance $\le 16$.